# PHP to only return mysql entries with a certain word in it (like twitter)

Tags: php, mysql, search, twitter

Twitters search returns all statuses with the word used in the search query. I'm just wondering how i could do this in PHP so it would only display the mysql entrys with that word in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a while loop on your result resource after making the database connection and echo out all the records one by one. Your query should look something like the one below depending on what the user entered. You should also echo at least a `<br>` between each loop!

```
SELECT * FROM tweets WHERE text LIKE '%word%';
```

Will show you all the tweets with 'word' in it.

---

Edit:

Since you are just trying to match on a word and not duplicate twitter's search algorithm, to get up and running the quickest use mysql's full text search. Thank you zerkms.

Comment: As well as rows contain `sword`.

Comment: You can use:

SELECT * FROM tweets WHERE text LIKE '% word %';

To avoid this problem!

Comment: The question is rather vague... Do you want to know how to read input from the user? Or should I first explain how to compile php with mysql. Better yet, how to install it on a specific distribution's package manager? Oh you're using windows? smh

Comment: zerkms -- Ya you're right my answer was bad. haha. lot going on that day. I would use postgres with "WHERE text ILIKE '% word%' or text ILIKE 'word%'" because I'm pretty sure that's exactly what the twitter api would return with q=word

Comment: @jcarlosn: what about `isn't,this,a,word?`?

Comment: @im3r3k: the same thing. Words are often limited not by spaces. Btw, you're completely wrong thinking that twitter ever uses `LIKE` keyword.

Comment: Oh so the asker wanted the ALGORITHM for twitter searching in sql? lol good luck. sphinx, solr, lucene even your precious full text searching won't cut it. =) It can't be duplicated! This question was doomed to fail. lol

Comment: All the asker wants is how to match on a word in sql. Why is this even a php question I wonder.

Answer (score 2):

Use [fulltext search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html) or 3rd party software like [sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/), solr, lucene, ...